# Terminate infinite loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, infinite-loop

I am trying to create a program that runs an infinite loop in parallel and exits the loops when it is told too. Specifically, the infinite loop is in the `square` function and the exiting signal is given when `shv='STOP'`. When all processes read that signal will have to exit the infinite loop and return.

The problem is that the `Processes` do not close even after giving the `STOP` signal.

Some notes:

- As many instances of multiprocessing code, this code runs in the terminal rather than in IDEs.

The code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import ctypes


def square(x, shv):

    while shv.value != 'STOP':
        time.sleep(3)
        print(shv.value)
    else:
        print('stopped')

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stopphrase = 'STOP'
    proecess_num = 2

    shv = mp.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, '')

    processes = [mp.Process(target=square, args=(i, shv)) for i in range(proecess_num)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    print('Mapped & Started')
    print(processes)

    while shv.value != stopphrase:
        inp = input('Type STOP and press Enter to terminate: ')
        if inp == stopphrase:
            shv.value = stopphrase
            time.sleep(2)
    p.terminate()
    print(processes)
```

For some reason this code gives the following in both cases of `print(processes)` even though I set the `shv.value = stopphrase`:

```
[<Process name='Process-1' pid=9664 parent=6084 started>, <Process name='Process -2' pid=10052 parent=6084 started>]
```

Please let me know for further improvements or details of the question.

Comment: A value cannot be a string, and you're getting an error that's not immediately being displayed due to the way multiprocessing handles stdout. you can't assign a string to a `Value` which can only be a single character. Strings need to be an array of characters. Better yet, check the user input in the main process, and then use a numeric value set to either 0 or 1 to signal the child.

Comment: You are right. thanks you! I changed the corresponding stings to characters ('STOP' to 'S' and ' ' to 'a') and all problems were solved

Comment: It's a little bit of a trap with python that there's no "char" data type like other languages. In python a "char" is actually a "string" of length 1. Other languages have a clear delineation between "char" and "string" (array of type char)

Comment: @Charalamm any feedback?

Comment: @Artiom I haven't had the time yet to test it. Thanks for your answer, it seems helpful and correct. I will give feedback as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to have a loop calling ‘join()’ on each process.

```py
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

instead of calling terminate on just one of them.

Comment: But you have already done ‘shv.value = stopphrase’ so there is no longer an infinite loop.

Comment: You are right, but for some reason `p.join()` does not stop the processes although `shv.value` is changing.  I will delete my previous comment. Also, in both cases `terminate` and `join`, `'stopped'` is not printed

Comment: The problem for some reason the problem was `ctypes`. I changed the corresponding stings to characters ('STOP'  to 'S' and ' ' to 'a') and all problems were solved